# Blank page when enabling SMB backend on Owncloud version 5

Tags: server-message-block, owncloud

Debian Squeeze, with Apache2 installed and running.

```
{"installed":"true","version":"5.0.25","versionstring":"5.0.13","edition":""}
http://servername.com/owncloud/status.php
```

My `owncloud/config/config.php` file:

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'instanceid' => '<gibberish>',
  'passwordsalt' => '<gibberish>',
  'datadirectory' => '/var/www/owncloud/data',
  'dbtype' => 'sqlite3',
  'version' => '5.0.25',
  'installed' => true,
);

"user_backends" => array (
        0 => array (
                "class"         => "OC_User_SMB",
                "arguments"     => array (
                        0 => 'localhost'
                        ),
                ),
        );
```

When I try accessing the main page (http://*server.com*/owncloud) or any of the .PHP files under it, I just get a blank page returned. If I comment out the last section for `userbackends`, it loads with the one user I've created. My goal is to have it authenticate against the SMB server that's running on the same system, as per [ownCloud's Documentation](http://doc.owncloud.org/server/5.0/admin_manual/configuration/custom_user_backend.html#smb). **How can I get ownCloud to authenticate against the Samba server running on the same box?**

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.

For diagnosing, ownCloud will spit out HTTP_500 errors. I checked my log at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, and saw that it was a parse error on line 11. I checked the PHP reference guide, and a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933793/unexpected-t-double-arrow-php) on Stackoverflow. I realized that I closed the array too quickly with the `);`. I moved it to the end, and put the stanza from ownCloud's SMB configuration into the `$CONFIG` section, and now I can authenticate as a regular user on my Samba server.

I edited it as such:

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'instanceid' => '<gibberish>',
  'passwordsalt' => '<gibberish>',
  'datadirectory' => '/var/www/owncloud/data',
  'dbtype' => 'sqlite3',
  'version' => '5.0.25',
  'installed' => true,

  "user_backends" => array (
        0 => array (
                "class"         => "OC_User_SMB",
                "arguments"     => array (
                        0 => 'localhost'
                        ),
                ),
        ),
);
```